# Using Python to search clinicaltrials.gov - SublimeText3 virtualenv behaving inconsistently

Tags: python, sublimetext3, python-module

I'm looking to query clinicaltrials.gov using Python through virtualenv in Sublime Text3. I came across a module at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clinical_trials/1.1.

I can install the module using:

```
pip install clinical_trials
```

after activating the virtualenv.

However doing:

```
from clinical_trials import Trials
```

generates the error `ImportError: No module named clinical_trials` when using virtualenv in ST3. I face no issues with other modules or packages (ex:Biopython) in the same virtualenv.

Has anybody used this module through a virtualenv? Are there other Python resources that I can use to query clinicaltrials.gov? What is causing the difference in behavior of modules inside the ST3 virtualenv?

This is my workflow:

1. Create new virtualenv using ST3
2. Activate the virtualenv using cmd
3. pip install needed packages
4. Run script in ST3

Comment: Are you using Python3? The module is only available for Python2.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. It's an ST3 issue. I've changed the question accordingly.

Comment: You can't *just* activate the virtualenv in cmd. You also need to activate it in ST3. virtualenv works by modifying the `PATH` in the local environment. It cannot change the `PATH` in a different program.

Comment: Yeah, I activated it in ST3 as well. I got some modules to work with the exact configuration but not clinical_trials. If I comment out the line importing it, the script runs fine.